# How to add a model in a Razor page from other location

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

My Model

```
public class UserRegistrationViewModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Index

```
@model UserRegistrationViewModel

<form asp-controller="Demo" asp-action="RegisterTextArea" method="post">
    <textarea asp-for="Description"></textarea>
    <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

Perfect up there but what happens if I have my Entity Domains declared in a class library project?

How can I place the address of that class on my razor page?

this sentence is correct? I'm currently making an error

```
@model DomainEntities.ViewModel.UserRegistrationViewModel
```

Another Example  I'm currently making an error

```
@model Domain.ViewModel.UserLogInViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

<form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login"
      asp-route-returnurl="@Model.ReturnUrl">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>

    <div>
        <label asp-for="Username"></label>
        <input asp-for="Username" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Username"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label asp-for="Password"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label asp-for="RememberMe"></label>
        <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
        <span asp-validation-for="RememberMe"></span>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: do you have a reference to your library project from your web project?

Comment: Also are these really Razor Pages? How come your model does not inherit from Page Model?

Comment: Are you using normal mvc instead?

Comment: If you are using Razor Pages take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if your `Web` project directly references your `DomainEntities` project then yes, it will work you just need to specify the full `namespace` to the `ViewModel`

```
@model My.Full.Namespace.DomainEntities.ViewModel.UserRegistrationViewModel
```

or maybe cleaner:

```
@using My.Full.Namespace.DomainEntities.ViewModel
@model UserRegistrationViewModel
```

for the second error, your `namespace` to the `ViewModel` is different, ie `Domain` vs `DomainEntities` It is likely that your `namespaces` are incorrect or are not fully spelled out.

If you are using some sort of `Dependency Injection` to inject your `DomainEntities` then without some crazy work-arounds your way will not work. The `Web` needs a direct dependency on the project with your `ViewModels`.

Finally, I question you putting your `ViewModels` in a separate project, I would say that for all except the most edge-case scenarios, your `ViewModels` should be in your `Web` project.